# Apple Watch app to trigger shell scripts on remote UNIX box

Tags: software-recommendation, unix, ssh, apple-watch

I've finally switched from a Pebble Smartwatch to an Apple Watch, and I need a replacement for this app: https://store-beta.rebble.io/app/568a4cfa496916a93f00004e

[image]

The watch displays a list of shell scripts. I select one of them, and the script is run over SSH. It's a very fast way to trigger all sorts of actions in my home.

Is there anything like this for the Apple Watch? I want something simple and minimilistic, and I do *not* want to rely on a third-party middleware service such as IFTTT.

Paid apps are fine if they are available for one-time purchase (as opposed to by subscription only). Apps distributed only in source code form are fine as well, as I have an Apple Developer account.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use an app such as [sshRequester](https://watchaware.com/watch-apps/1090960133).

Comment: "The item you’ve requested is not currently available in the U.S. store."